# $(window).resize(); doesn't work - REVISIT

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script where I even out the heights of the content on containers inside a wrapper div. It simply won't recalculate/reset the height on `resize` (on refresh it works).

I know this matter is answered in many places, and I believe I have read them all, but my script still wont run on resize.

Can you tell me what's wrong? Thanks!

```js
var $equalboxContainer = $('.equalbox-container');
if ($equalboxContainer.length) {
  function equalheight(container) {
    $(container).each(function() {
      var highestBox = 0;
      $('.equal-box', this).each(function() {
        if ($(this).height() > highestBox) {
          highestBox = $(this).height();
        }
      });
      $('.equal-box', this).height(highestBox);
    });
  };

  equalheight($equalboxContainer);

  $(window).resize(function() {
    equalheight($equalboxContainer);
  });
}
```

Comment: Without seeing a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the issue it's hard to say exactly what the issue is. I'd suggest putting in some `console.log()` calls to check the values which are calculated and see how the logic flows.

Comment: well you set heights so not sure how they will adjust on resize since they have a fixed height.

Comment: perhaps remove the style attribute on resize so you don't start with inline height styles

Comment: @epascarello the resize is on the `window`, not the element they are setting the height on?

Comment: @Taplar and your point is? If you set the height on an element does it change on resize?

Comment: It would if you update the elements height, driven off of the resize of the window.

Comment: BUT they are already all set to a fixed height.... My div that is 100px is not going to change after I set it to 100px. So first time the code runs it sets it to the highest. Second time it runs, they are all the same value.

Comment: I read your first comment as saying the resize was based on the element with the fixed height.  I may have misread that.

Comment: Solution remove the fixed heights before reading heights

Comment: @Pete : it seems your answer was the closed solution. I needed to remove the fixed height, so set $(this).height('auto'), and now it works.. Thanks alot! :)

Answer (score 0):

it works for me i dont understand why it wouldnt maybe try using the venila js alternative

```js
$(window).resize(function(e) { //adds events for func to
   console.log('resize')
  }); //end bracket
  // or venila js
  window.addEventListener('resize', function(e){ //adds events for func
  console.log('resize');
 }); //end bracket
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```